# changing an input value using YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

I want to use the [YUI calendar widget](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/calendar-simple.html) to provide users with a way of selecting the date for an input form.

The question I need anwered is how to do I change the value of input elements using YUI?

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="dateEntry" value="I NEED TO KNOW HOW TO CHANGE THIS!" />
```

I've looked everywhere but can't find anything.

And if this isn't possible using YUI, is it possible using jQuery or another library? And if so is there a similar calendr module I can use alongside a library that can do this?

Hope that makes sense :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the value try this:

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
  var input = Y.one('#dateEntry');
  input.set('value', 'new value!');
});
```

**[HERE](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/properties.html)** is the documentation.

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/ogejop/edit#javascript,html,live)** is a working example.